# Customized Progressbar as indicator in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Is there any way to make a `ProgressBar` [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQTZ4.jpg%20in%20android.).

Or can it be achieved by customizing `RatingBar` as an indicator?

If so, how would I be able to attach the lines in between the circles?

Comment: it's better just to make custom view to make that thing.
For example you can use imageview that will show that line and 4 views with that circles, not difficult and quickly to do

Comment: @BrainAmplifier18 you can achieve it using images.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using different images which represents different stages of your process

keep an imageview with visibility gone and make it visible when you want to display the same

in your drawable folder keep an xml like the following progressanimation.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:oneshot="false">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressone" android:duration  ="400" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/progresstwo" android:duration="400" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressthree" android:duration="400" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/progressfour" android:duration="400" />

    </animation-list>

    and use this as background of your ImageView like follows

                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progressanimation);
                final AnimationDrawable mailAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) iv
                        .getBackground();
                iv.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mailAnimation != null)
                            mailAnimation.start();
                        System.out.println("anim wrkingggg");
                    }
                });
```

here iv is your imageview.This code will change the background automatically.You can make the runnable run with your own timelimit.

Comment: could you also add how this can be implemented with a layout? and also where can I add the lines in between the progress images?

Comment: I told you to save different images for this like one image should be step1 to step two with blueline and remaining with ash or fadeline.2nd image should be step1 to step3 with blue line and remaining fade line like this you can keep images as you want to display.The ImageView to show this can be placed as centerInparent for a relativelayout or garvity center for a linerar layout if you post the xml code and tell me where you wish to display the same I'll edit it for you

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I ended up using progressbar in between the imageviews. I used your logic of making it visible programmatically once the step is complete and using the method setProgress(100), setMax(100) for the progress.

Comment: follow up question for this SO question, do I still need to post how i did my answer?